# React.js : TypeError: values.hobbies is not iterable and also getting error while displaying the college name on the userslist page

Tags: reactjs

1.How can I iterate over hobbies array in AddUser.js file ,I am not getting it. I tried using map function but it is throwing some iterable error.How can I iterate over a checkbox?
2.When I am trying to  display the college name in UsersList.js file it is throwing errors and when I visit the userlist page, the page appears to be blank.It displays nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code :

AddUser.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
 Form,
 FormGroup,
 Label,
 Input,
 Button,
 Col
 } from 'reactstrap'
 import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'
 import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
 import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
 import axios from 'axios'
 const AddUser = () => {
 const { addUser } = useContext(GlobalContext)
 const history = useHistory()
 const [values, setValues] = useState({
 fullname: '',
 birthdate: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/'),
 address: '',
 gender: '',
 college: [],
 hobbies: []
 })

 const handleSubmit = () => {
 const newUser = {
  id: uuid(),
  fullname: values.fullname,
  birthdate: values.birthdate,
  address: values.address,
  college: values.college,
  gender: values.gender,
  hobbies: values.hobbies
  }
  addUser(newUser)
  history.push('/userslist')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData(name) {
  const response = await axios.get(`http://universities.hipolabs.com/search`, {
    params: { name }
  }
  )
  console.log(response.data)
  setValues({ college: response.data })
  }
  fetchData('Middle')
  }, [])

  const handleChange = e => {
  setValues({
  ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
  }
  const handleCheckboxChange = event => {
  let newArray = [...values.hobbies, event.target.id];
   if (values.hobbies.includes(event.target.id)) {
   newArray = newArray.filter(hobby => hobby !== event.target.id);
   }
   setValues({
   hobbies: newArray
   })
   }
   return (
   <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <FormGroup>
    <Label>Name</Label>
    <Input type='text' placeholder='Enter Name'
      value={values.fullname}
      onChange={handleChange}
      name='fullname'
    />
   </FormGroup>
   <FormGroup>
    <Label>BirthDate</Label>
    <Input type='date'
      placeholder='Enter BirthDate'
      value={values.birthdate} onChange={handleChange}
      name='birthdate'
    />
   </FormGroup>
   <FormGroup>
    <Label>Address</Label>
    <Input type='textarea'
      placeholder='Enter Address'
      value={values.address} onChange={handleChange}
      name='address' />
   </FormGroup>
   <FormGroup row>
    <Label for="exampleSelect" sm={2}>Select College Name</Label>
    <Col sm={10}>
      <Input type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect" onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value='' disabled hidden>College List</option>
        {values.college &&
          values.college.map((col, index) => {
            return <option value={col.name} key={index + 1}>{col.name}</option>
          })
        }
      </Input>
    </Col>
   </FormGroup>
   <FormGroup tag="fieldset">
    <Label>Please Select Gender</Label>
    <FormGroup>
      <Label>
        <Input type='radio' name='gender'
          onChange={handleChange}
          value='Male'
          checked={values.gender === "Male"}
        />
        Male
      </Label>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
      <Label >
        <Input type='radio' name='gender'
          onChange={handleChange}
          value='Female'
          checked={values.gender === "Female"} />
        Female
      </Label>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
      <Label>
        <Input type='radio' name='gender'
          onChange={handleChange}
          value='Other'
          checked={values.gender === 'Other'} />
      Other
      </Label>
    </FormGroup>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
      <Input type="checkbox" name="travelling" value='travelling' id="exampleCheck" onChange= 
   {handleCheckboxChange} />
      <Label for="exampleCheck">Travelling</Label>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
      <Input type="checkbox" name="reading" value='reading' id="exampleCheck" onChange= 
     {handleCheckboxChange} />
      <Label for="exampleCheck">Reading</Label>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
      <Input type="checkbox" name="gaming" value='gaming' id="exampleCheck" onChange= 
   {handleCheckboxChange} />
      <Label for="exampleCheck">Gaming</Label>
    </FormGroup>
    </FormGroup>
    {values.hobbies && values.hobbies.map((hobby, index) => {
    return <p key={index}>{hobby}</p>
  })}
    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
    </Form>
    )
   }

   export default AddUser



    UsersList.js

   import React, { useContext } from 'react'
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
   import {
     Button,
    Table
    } from 'reactstrap'
   import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'

   const UsersList = () => {
   const { users, removeUser } = useContext(GlobalContext)
   console.log(users)
    return (

    <Table dark>
        {users.length > 0 ? <>
            {users.map((user) => (<>
      <thead>
       <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th> Name</th>
       <th>BirthDate</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
       <th>College</th>
       <th>Update Action</th>
       <th>Delete Action</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody >
     <tr key={user.id}>
      <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
      <td>{user.fullname}</td>
      <td>{user.birthdate}</td>
      <td>{user.address}</td>
      <td>{user.gender}</td>
    <td>{user.college}</td>
      <td><Link className='btn btn-warning mr-1' to={`/edituser/${user.id}`}>Edit</Link></td>
      <td><Button color='danger' onClick={()=>removeUser(user.id)}>Delete</Button></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody></>))}
        </> : <p>No Users Found</p>}
    </Table>
     )
     }

     export default UsersList
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the component and pass the values object to method and loop the college values and then create the options inside the loop and return them.

For example :

```
createCollegeOptions(var values){

    let collegeOptions = [];

    for(let i =0; i < values.college.length; i++){
        collegeOptions.push(
            <option key={i} value = {values[i].college}>{values[i].college}</option>
        )
    }
    
    return collegeOptions;
    
}
```

Call the above method in render like this :

```
<div>
    <select>
        {this.createCollegeOptions()}
    </select>
</div>
```